# How to use the react hook "useMemo" with asynchronous functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-hooks

How can I await, to resolve/reject, the promise returned by a function wrapped in the react hook "useMemo"?

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
  // Get the persisted email/username
  const persistedUsername = useMemo(async () => {
    let username;

    try {
      username = await AsyncStorage.getData(`@${ASYNC_STORAGE_KEY}:username`);
    } catch {}

    return username;
  }, []);
```

---

### EDIT

What I am trying to achieve is to get the data before the component is rendered, some kind of "componentWillMount" life-cycle. My two options were:

1. Computing the value using useMemo hook to avoid unnecessary recomputations.
2. Combine useEffect + useState. Not the best idea because useEffect runs after the component paints.

@DennisVash has proposed the solution to this problem in the comments:

Blocking all the visual effects using the useLayoutEffect hook (some kind of componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate) where the code runs immediately after the DOM has been updated, but before the browser has had a chance to "paint" those changes.

---

As you can see, persistedUsername is still a promise (I am not waiting the result of the asynchronous function)...

Any ideas? Is it not a good idea to perform asynchronous jobs with this hook? Any custom hook?

Also, what are the disadvantages of performing this operation in this way compared to using useEffect and useState?

Same thing with useEffect and useState:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Get the persisted email/username
    (async () => {
      const persistedUsername = await AsyncStorage.getData(
        `@${ASYNC_STORAGE_KEY}:username`
      );

      emailOrUsernameInput.current.setText(persistedUsername);
    })();
  }, []);
```

Thank you.

Comment: So declare a promise inside the `useMemo` and call it?...

Comment: seems to me more of a usecase for `useEffect` and `useState` instead

Comment: @thedude Yes, I also thought the same, but maybe it is possible to do this with useMemo (I have never used it for asynchronous operations).

Comment: Do you know the differences between `useEffect` and `useMemo`? They do not serve the same purpose, why would you make an async action in `useMemo`? Are you basically asking what is the difference between them?

Comment: @DennisVash useEffect is to perform actions after the rendering, the last execution of the component, right? And useMemo to perform weight actions, avoiding re-computing them in each render.

Comment: Basically, I have thought to use it here, because if the process of getting the persisted username wasn't async, it would make sense to perform this before the rendering (some kind of componentWillMount life-cycle)

Comment: So you ask how to use `componentWillMount` with hooks? Try searching a bit, it's almost identical for `useLayoutEffect` usage

Comment: Your question sounds like an XY problem https://xyproblem.info/, where you asking about your attempted solution with `useMemo` and `useEffect` instead of asking about the real problem you trying to solve.

Comment: @DennisVash my fault, sorry, I will try to edit the question to make the problem easier to understand. Also, thank you very much for the information, it solved my problem, I didn't know about the useLayoutEffect hook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the question is about how to use `componentWillMount` with hooks which is almost equivalent to [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) (since `componentWillMount` is deprecated).

For more additional info, you should **NOT** resolve `async` action in `useMemo` since you will block the thread (and JS is single-threaded).

Meaning, you will wait until the promise will be resolved, and then it will continue with computing the component.

On other hand, async hooks like `useEffect` is a better option since it won't block it.